# Core Graphics' CGBlendModes seem (partially) not consistent with PDF specs

Tags: ios, pdf, core-graphics

I am running into some weird behavior with CGBlendMode in Core Graphics.
My understanding is that the first 16 blend modes (normal (0) to luminosity (15)) are based straight on the PDF specification https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf.

(I am working with RGB blending space only and opaqueness is always 1.)
My observed trouble is that when I implement the blendmodes manually based on the PDF specification and then compare to the colors to what core graphics paints, I get in some cases discrepancies.
For example, according to the PDF specs of ColorBurn (p.325), when using sourceColor black (0,0,0) on backdropColor green (0,1,0) in colorBurn blend mode, the blended color should be black.

So if I run this code below, there should be a small black square showing on top of a larger green square (as shown on the right). But the actual blending result is the one on the left.

I get similar weirdness with ColorDodge and Hue and some others.

I have tried on several iOS devices and simulators and the errors are consistent across. Does anyone have some idea what I am doing wrong or misunderstanding?

Or am I wrong to assume that CoreGraphics and the PDF specification should match with regards to blend modes?

```
 public override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    
        let blendColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let bigSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100) // Size of backdrop square
        let smallSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 60, height: 60) // Size of source square
        
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        
        context.saveGState()
        
        // Draw opaque green backdrop
        let bdColor = CGColor(colorSpace: blendColorSpace, components: [0,1,0,1])! // Green (alpha 1)
        context.setFillColor(bdColor)
        context.setAlpha(1)
        context.setBlendMode(.normal)
        let origin = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
        context.addRect(CGRect(origin: origin, size: bigSize))
        context.drawPath(using: .fill)
        
        // Draw opaque black smaller square on top with colorburn
        let scColor = CGColor(colorSpace: blendColorSpace, components: [0,0,0,1])! // Black (alpha 1)
        context.setFillColor(scColor)
        context.setBlendMode(.colorBurn)
        context.addRect(CGRect(origin: origin, size: smallSize))
        context.drawPath(using: .fill)
        
        context.restoreGState()
    }
```

[image: Left is the CG reality, right what I would expect from the PDF specs.]

Answer (score 0):

It's just that your background color is too bright, so it refuses any darkening. Use a less intense background color and you'll see the darkening you expect.

Here's a simpler example (I use HSB notation because these blend modes depend upon luminance):

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let bigSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    let smallSize = CGSize(width: 60, height: 60)

    let brightness: CGFloat = 0.998 // **
    UIColor.init(hue: 0.3, saturation: 1, brightness: brightness, alpha: 1)
        .setFill()
    UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: bigSize))
        .fill(with: .normal, alpha: 1)

    UIColor.init(hue: 0.0, saturation: 1, brightness: 0.0, alpha: 1)
        .setFill()
    UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: smallSize))
        .fill(with: .colorBurn, alpha: 1)
}
```

The `brightness` of the background color is `0.998`. If it is any higher, there is no darkening of the background color.

Comment: So you say that the Core Graphics blend modes are different from the PDF blend modes? According to the PDF spec a 0 source always results in 0 for ColorBurn...

Comment: Indeed, if I replace the green (0,1,0) by "almost-green" (0,0.99,0), I obtain the expected blending result. Could you elaborate on the "refuses any darkening". So what is the mathematical formula for the colordodge in CoreGraphics? Is it a bug (and it should actually be as in PDF, where there is no such "refusal") or a feature (and CG does it on purpose). It is not about this specific example but in general about understanding the formula by which CG does all its blending of these 16 modes that I probably falsely assumed copies from the PDF standard.

Comment: I don't know why you would think this has anything to do with PDF. Added some example code to illustrate what I meant in the first paragraph.

Comment: Yes I see your example and it matches mine when I use the "almost-green" instead of the green (0,1,0). CoreGraphics has a lot to do with PDF. Quartz uses the PDF standard's drawing model internally. And all the blend modes, at least in name. So that is why I thought they should match.

Comment: OK, well, I've said all I can say. You asked why you weren't seeing any darkening and I told you how to see some. :)